# How can I catch this PHP connection error?

Tags: php, curl

**Here's the Problem:**

On some websites, my code that connects to Twitter is generating a fatal error that stops PHP from running for the rest of the page load. It creates a total page kill. How can I catch this error so that I can simply display zeroes or use one of the tweet counts from the most previous successful connections?

Presumably, this is because a site that has this code on it has hit the Twitter API limits. But in the rare cases where that does happen, I need it to fail gracefully so that I can just use my previously fetched tweet count.

**Here's the code:**

If the user has the Twitter Button active, we fetch the share count:

```
$social = new shareCount($url);
if( $options['twitter'] ) $tweets = $social->get_tweets();
```

This is where that function request gets passed inside the shareCount class:

```
function get_tweets() { 
    $json_string = file_get_contents_curl('https://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->url);
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
}
```

And this is the file_get_contents_curl() function which is, I believe where the error is occurring and is where we need to catch the error.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url){
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    $cont = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }
    return $cont;
}
```

This is the error that is being generated:

```
connect() timed out!
```

**This is the requested solution:**

So the question is, how do I catch that error and have the file_get_contents_curl() function either return a zero or return a specific code that I can look for indicating quietly to my script that it failed to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two timeout settings for cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);        // Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);               // Timeout in seconds
```

Set them both and cURL will fail gracefully on a timeout of either type.

However, slow DNS resolutions will trigger SIGALRM which cURL interprets as the timeout alarm. Add this to quiet that alarm, and any alarms that will halt the PHP execution:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
```

You should continue to be checking for cURL errors and dealing with them, not suppressing them, like this:

```
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
if ($curl_errno > 0) {
    // Deal with error
}
```

Comment: It's seriously that simple!? Wow. I'm headed to go do that, but also to go research how those settings work. Thank you for pointing me to that so quickly.

Comment: That's doesn't seem to have fixed it. It's still giving the hard error.

Comment: @NicholasCardot Sorry I didn't reply sooner. I updated my answer with a proper way to deal with these errors. You should not be suppressing them as the other answer suggests.

Comment: I had to switch which answer I accepted. This one did the trick while the other did not.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use `@` to suppress any errors that are thrown. These errors will not be shown and the script will continue to execute. Just put `@` in front of any line that you think causes the error.

You can put it here where you are calling the function

```
function get_tweets() { 
    $json_string = @file_get_contents_curl('https://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->url); // This will not throw any errors if file_get_contents_curl() fails.
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
}
```

Or you can put it in your function, at any line where you think the error is caused.

Comment: In the event that it does throw and error, what value will it return to the $json_string variable?

Comment: I am not sure. Either it will return `false` or the content of the error. I think that the second one is more likely, though you can test it out

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Although it didn't work in front of the function like that. I had to place it in the curl_exec() function.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work when you put it before the function call. You could try putting it in front of `$json_string` , the variable which calls the function.But you managed to fix by putting it in front of the function, so I wouldn't bother